# Cannot access nginx container through external IP of Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud vm running an nginx docker container on port 8080. The nginx page is accessible from within the machine when I use `curl http://localhost:8080`. However, when I open the External IP of the machine (using port 8080), I get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in chrome. I had enabled the http/https firewall options while creating the VM.

Here is the docker run command that I used and the curl check on localhost:

```
aayush_pathak15@instance-1:~/devops-environment$ sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx
f398231940eeb7194e0b4deb50936d7581cf32a451583e162cac40e829f9ebff
aayush_pathak15@instance-1:~/devops-environment$ curl http://localhost:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>
<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>
<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
aayush_pathak15@instance-1:~/devops-environment$
```

Here is a list of all ports on my VM (and docker listening to port 8080)

```
aayush_pathak15@instance-1:~/devops-environment$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      583/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      8936/docker-proxy   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      583/sshd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           310/dhclient        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           402/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                402/chronyd
```

I tried adding another firewall rule to allow all ports (please ignore the unrelated naming that says "jenkins")
[image]

Below are my machine details

[image]

Could this have anything to do with the "IP Forwarding" being off? (See above image)

Comment: Can we see how you deployed the nginx container? What tool did you use, command line on the node, Google Cloud Console? What arguments did you run with it?

Comment: I simply did "docker run -d -p 8080:80 nginx" and the container was successfully up and running. Curling localhost:8080 was giving me the correct nginx default page. But it did not open using the external IP of vm on my browser

Comment: Is Nginx listening on `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`? Show the config files in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Nginx is listening to localhost on my VM. I have included a curl output in my question along with a list of all open ports (to show port 8080 is certainly in use by docker). Please let me know if that answers your question

Comment: If you configure Nginx to listen on `localhost`, you cannot access the service from the Internet. Change the listen address to `0.0.0.0`. `localhost` is only accessible inside the OS via the loopback device. Think of `localhost` as a private network inside the OS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran my container using

```
sudo docker run -d -p [Internal IP]:8080:80 nginx
```

and I could access the nginx page on http://[External IP]:8080

Also it was necessary to add the firewall rule mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) The `-p 8080:80` argument in your docker run statement is telling it to publish port 8080 on the host to port 80 on the container, so in this case you would access it externally by visiting the node's external IP on port 8080. `34.68.171.6:8080`

Comment: Apologies. I was using port 8080 with the external IP as well. I have edited the question to clarify that.